# JQuery plugin for form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I would like to validate my form fields *instantly* (probably on `change` event) instead of validating the whole form upon submit. It should look like the *Pinterest* sign-up [form](https://pinterest.com/join/register/)

Which `jquery plugin` would you recommend for that?

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: If it's only one form, you don't really need a plug-in to abstract the task... If you're an intermediate level developer you could probably implement a working solution just as fast as you could add, learn, configure a jQuery plug-in. With something this trivial I don't consider it re-inventing the wheel... couldn't you have just searched on jquery's plug-in gallery, there must be 50 validation plug-ins and everyone will have there own opinion with no definitive answer (or best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery validation plugin:

> The plugin is written and maintained by Jörn Zaefferer, a member of
>   the jQuery team, lead developer on the jQuery UI team and maintainer
>   of QUnit. It was started back in the early days of jQuery in 2006, and
>   updated and improved since then.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

[Demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [jQuery Validate](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation). I use it and love it. Pretty much all you have to do is add the class `required` and it will follow the html5 tag type of `email`, `number` etc and make sure it matches